# Vim: command-line grep-like search with Ctrl-P and Ctrl-N

Tags: vim

Basically, I don't want to use my arrow keys completely.

But for that to happen the Ctrl-P needs 
to have the same functionality in 
the command-line as my Up arrow key.

For Example, I type

```
:so
```

then I press Up, it turns like so

```
:source $MYVIMRC
```

but when I press Ctrl-P, it only goes to the last executed
command

```
:h camelcasemotion
```

Can anyone help me with this? It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In command mode, [<Up>](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_%3CUp%3E) does “move to the previous command in the history that matches the string entered so far”.

In command mode,
[CTRL-P](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-P) has two functions.

- After a Tab completion that has multiple possibilities, it does “show the previous matching value”.
  Think of it as backward Tab. Most terminals do not distinguish Tab from Shift-Tab, but it and CTRL-P are the same mapping in GUI versions of Vim.
- Without a preceding Tab completion, it does “move to the previous command in the history” (without trying to match the text entered so far).

You can remap CTRL-P to be the same as <Up> if you really want to:

```
:cmap <C-P> <Up>
```

You might also want to remap CTRL-N, too:

```
:cmap <C-N> <Down>
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for.

I should've looked for :help to remap Command-line.
How silly of me, thanks a lot, it really helped.